# Assigning value over a ForLoop in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, nan

I have a database like this:

```
manufacturer  cylinders    description
0   toyota   5 cylinders   toyota, gmc 10 years old.
1   NaN          NaN       gmc, Motor runs and drives good.
2   NaN          NaN       Motor old, in pieces. 4 cylinders
3   NaN     12 cylinders   2 owner 0 rust. Cadillac.
```

And this set of keywords:

```
manufacturer = ['gmc', 'toyota', 'cadillac']
cylinders = ['12 cylinders', '4 cylinders', '5 cylinders']
```

I want to create a program that reads the description and based on the keywords needed, adds the right information to each column.Ideally, it would look like this:

```
    manufacturer  cylinders   description
0   toyota      5 cylinders   toyota, gmc 10 years old.
1   gmc             NaN       gmc, Motor runs and drives good.
2   NaN         4 cylinders   Motor old, in pieces. 4 cylinders
3   cadillac   12 cylinders   2 owner 0 rust. Cadillac.
```

Been trying about everything but nothing seems to work. This is what I tried in order to add the words to one column, but I need to change it to more than one columns and this program changes the value even if it is not NaN (f.e changes "toyota" to "gmc"), which i don't want.

```
import re
keyword = ['gmc', 'toyota', 'cadillac']
bag_of_words = []
for i, description in enumerate(test3['description']):
bag_of_words = re.findall(r"""[A-Za-z\-]+""", test3["description"][i])
for word in bag_of_words: 
    if word.lower() in keyword:
            test3.loc[i, 'manufacturer'] = word.lower()
```

Any idea on how could I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a for loop. Instead you can use `pandas` vectorized funcitons.

1. You can use `fillna()` with `.str.extract()` with the `pandas` library. Essentially, you are replacing `NaN` values with the extracted information from the description column.
2. You can pass a flag, `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to ignore case-sensitivity when matching.
3. Finally, we have to use `, expand=False` to return a series, because `str.extract()` returns a dataframe, which will cause an error when doing `.fillna()` on a dataframe rather than a series.

---

```
import pandas
import re
keyword = ['gmc', 'toyota', 'cadillac']
df['manufacturer'] = df['manufacturer'].fillna(
    df['description'].str.extract('(gmc|toyota|cadillac)', flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False))
df['cylinders'] = df['cylinders'].fillna(
    df['description'].str.extract('(\d+\s+cylinders?)', flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False))
df
Out[1]: 
  manufacturer     cylinders                        description
0       toyota   5 cylinders          toyota, gmc 10 years old.
1          gmc           NaN   gmc, Motor runs and drives good.
2          NaN   4 cylinders  Motor old, in pieces. 4 cylinders
3     Cadillac  12 cylinders          2 owner 0 rust. Cadillac.
```

If you need the output to be lowrcase you can add `str.lower()` or `str.casefold()` to the end of each line of code above for each column. The `casefold()` operation is like `lower()` but is more reliable with symbols and different languages.